# How to disable responsive grid in Foundation 6

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm currently developing a responsive website with the new Foundation 6 but I can't seem to find how to disable the responsive grid (I need to make it optional for the customer) by the tutorials for version 5.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I used <meta name="viewport" content="width=1030, initial-scale=1"> and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this **meta** tag from header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

You also have option to use [Responsive Switch](http://filzhut.net/projects/responsive-switch/) by filzhut.

Comment: I did this, but the block grids are still being applied.

Comment: Are you resizing your browser to see if the responsiveness are gone?

Comment: Using Device emulator in Chrome.

Comment: Try it on the actual device. Most device emulators act as regular desktop/laptop browser. you can always fix your `row`, `columns-` to fix width, something i don't recommend.

Comment: Actually even on the real device. I have fixed row atm, columns are working ok (not resizing) but the block grid is still resizing.

Comment: Weird. add fix width to block grid too, example: `.small-block-grid-3`

Comment: or use this [Responsive Switch](http://filzhut.net/projects/responsive-switch/) this also allow you to make it optional for customers

Answer (score 0):

### Remove the styling for the row, column and columns classes.

Add this css code block to the header **after** the foundation css links on each page you desire to remove the grid styling. Or, you can include the style in your foundation css file at the bottom:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .row, .column, .columns { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; float: none !important; display: block !important; position: static !important; width : auto !important;  max-width: none !important; clear: none !important; }
</style>
```

---

Here is what I mean by adding the style to the bottom of the foundation.min.css file to remove grid styling. Also, this means you will have to host the css file locally and not use a cdn.

[image: Image of foundation.min.css file with style added at bottom to remove grid]

---

Now, as for giving your customer a choice of grid or no grid, you can show them two dev sites, one with the grid and one without the grid. Or, you could put a button or some element on the page and use js to add and remove the css or an element in a form to do it with a server script. In your question you referenced:

> by the tutorials in for version 5

I didn't find any tutorial for f5 with a switch for the grid css, provide a link and I may update this answer.